# how to add values and print it out

Tags: perl

Hi I have some thing like this in my file

```
147.840 15.12
188.160 15.12
678.720 15.12
565.440 15.12
```

No I want to add 0.76 to the first number and 7.84 to second number. I want to do it to all numbers in the file. the output should be the like this(sum)

```
147.840+0.56 15.12+7.84
188.160+0.56 15.12+7.84
678.720+0.56 15.12+7.84
565.440+0.56 15.12+7.84
```

How can I do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using perl one liner,

```
perl -lane 'print join " ", $F[0]+0.76, $F[1]+7.84' file
```

Switches explanation,

- -l chomps every line and adds newline when printing
- -a auto split (on whitespaces) into `@F` array
- -n adds `while(<>) {}` loop around code
- -e takes code as parameter

Answer (score 2):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -lape '$F[0] += 0.76; $F[1] += 7.84; $_ = "@F"' file
```

**Switches**:

- `-l`: Enable line ending processing
- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Comment: Unfortunately nobody predicted elegant assignment for `$,` from command line, so `print $F[0]+0.76, $F[1]+7.84` would be possible.